# Is psychologism still a thing? What are common rejections of psychologism?

Tags: epistemology, philosophy-of-mathematics, psychology

Recently, I learnt that there exist people who go so far as to claim that "mathematics is a branch of psychology". I thought that psychologism was long outdated, in connection with mathematics at least since Frege?

What are some good rejections of psychologism?

Comment: uh phenomenology!

Comment: In a sense, psychologism triumphed in analytic philosophy after the decline of logicism and logical positivism. Quine openly declared:"*The old epistemology aspired to contain, in a sense, natural
science; it would construct it somehow from sense data. Epistemology
in its new setting, conversely, is contained in natural
science, as a chapter of psychology.*" Of course, it is a more sophisticated version of psychologism than Mill's was in 19th century, see [SEP's Psychologism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/psychologism/#RecReEva).